# How do you access the Draw toolbar symbol(s) from ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap, symbology

I'm dropping a text element onto a map and I'd like to use whatever settings the **Draw** toolbar has (font, size, color, etc).

Is there a convenient way to access symbol interfaces?  Or do you have to create those from the individual settings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QI/cast from `IApplication.Document` to [`IDocumentDefaultSymbols`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v000000mz000000) and access its properties, which include default line, marker, text and fill symbols.

Comment: Perfect!  I'm glad I asked the question. And I can't believe I haven't needed this before now! Thanks!